# how to read the csv file in robot framework for data verification

Tags: csv, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to read a CSV file for data verification. Any library or Keywords for reading CSV file would do. I am using Robot Framework with Ride.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily create your own library in python for reading and writing csv files. Doing so lets you create any keywords you want. You could simply read and return all the data, or have a keyword that returns the number of rows, or the number of columns, or anything else.

**Example keyword to read a csv file:**

Save the following definition in a file named `csvLibrary.py`. It creates a keyword library with a single keyword named "read csv file". Pass is the path to a csv file and it will return the data as a list of lists.

```
import csv
class csvLibrary(object):

    def read_csv_file(self, filename):
        '''This creates a keyword named "Read CSV File"

        This keyword takes one argument, which is a path to a .csv file. It
        returns a list of rows, with each row being a list of the data in 
        each column.
        '''
        data = []
        with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                data.append(row)
        return data
```

**Example test:**

This test will use the csvLibrary to open up a .csv file, read it, and return the result as a list of lists:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | csvLibrary.py

*** Test cases *** 
| Reading a csv file
| | ${data}= | read csv file | test.csv
| | log | ${data}
```

Comment: Confusion in this line. | | ${data}= | read csv file | test.csv
What is test.csv and read csv file?? What's in ${data} veriable?

Comment: `read csv file` is the keyword we created in the library (`def read_csv_file`). As I wrote in the answer, it returns a list of lists. So, `${data[0]}` will have the first row of data, `${data[0][0]}` is the first column of the first row, etc. If you run the code and then look at the log, you'll see exactly what is in ${data}.

Comment: @AdnanGhaffar: it sounds like you typed everything into a cell in RIDE. THis test is in pipe-separated format. You'll have to adjust to get it to work in whatever format you're using. `${data}=` goes in one cell, `read csv file` goes in another, `test.csv` goes in another.

Comment: Thanks it works :) adnan.ghaffar07 is my Skype id please join me there and share some books for reading etc.

Comment: @BryanOakley, thank you for the answer. So, in order to loop it thru the data, it may be useful to get the row and column sizes by having additional functions in python script, right? Can it also be used to fetch the data using column names.

Comment: @Rao: yes, it could be used to fetch data using column names. Not the code as posted, but it is quite possible to write that code.

Comment: @BryanOakley, that is so quick reply, thank you so much. Just started using rf, loving it. Had a data driven tests, but some how like to have data in  a separate file rather than to have in robot script. This is very good lead to externalize the data. I'll give a try to do the same.  Very new to python, have to take some efforts which I like to do.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar thing as follows:

`${content} |  Get File |  ${dir}/Newfolder2/random.xml
Should Contain  |    ${content} |  ${text}`

where:
${content}, ${dir} and ${text} are just some variables (names should be rather self-explanatory) and
Get File and Should Contain are standard keywords (for Get File you have to import OperatingSystem lib)

Answer (score 0):

i would fix the for loop that you wrote in your py script first. i ran into the exact same issue where i would have to call a subset of subset in my list index (ie data[0][0] instead of data[0]). I wrote my for loop like this:

```
data = []
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='<something here>')
     for row in reader:
        for i in row:
             data.append(i)
return data
```

if your csv file comes from excel, you can use the argument:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
```

as well