# How to data parametrization in robot framework

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I am basically trying to learn data parametrization in robot framework (mostly with web based testing as the context). I have 4 points which i am looking to get covered . All the four point  are related to each other a lot.

1. First one - A code problem

   I was looking to iterate a values of a list variable using for loop and was unable to access the nth value .

I am able to use the following with no errors:

```
Input Text  //textarea[@id="MainContent_txtAddress"]    @{Address}[1]
```

But when i am using a for loop to access the values I am getting this error:

```
Starting test: RobotFrameworkcode.Nsure.ForLoop
20150105 18:26:05.484 :  FAIL : Resolving variable '${jobcode[i]}' failed: NameError: name 'i' is not defined
Ending test:   RobotFrameworkcode.Nsure.ForLoop
```

The for loop snippet which is causing the error .

```html
ForLoopTest
    : FOR    ${i}    IN    Range    |0|    |1|
    \    Log to Console    @{jobcode[i]}
```

Is there a better way to access the value of a list variable at n th element .
Are list variables similar to arrays ?

2. I want to pass values to textboxes in a data entry form in
   parametrized format through excel sheet or csv or through a
   collection of list variables representing a page, Is that possible
   in robot framework ? Need help with examples and sample code on the
   same . I could not find much content on the internet regarding the
   same.
3. Any other ideas on how others did data parametrization in general in
   robot framework. What robot framework tools or concepts where used
   for the same ?
4. Thirdly,I would like to know if there are any good tutorials or
   websites or videos to help learn robot framework in general . The
   official documentation is good , but i am looking for more content
   example wise,so as to enable the beginners to be able to relate
   faster with the concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. NameError: name 'i' is not defined**

When you use the extended variable syntax, everything inside the curly braces is evaluated by the python interpreter. However, the `i` in your code is a robot variable, not a python variable. Also, to access an individual element of an array you need to use `$` rather than `@`. In order to do what you want, you need to do it like this:

```
Log to Console    ${jobcode[${i}]}
```

**2. Parameters from excel**

You can create a robot library that reads data from a csv file. You can also do that with a .xls file. See this answer for an example of reading a csv file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21859360/7432

**3. Any other ideas on how others did data parametrization?**

My team uses YAML files to define test data. It's also possible to read from XML files, or any other format that is readable via python. Robot lets you expose python methods as keywords, so anything you can do in python you can do in a robot test.

**4. I would like to know if there are any good tutorials or websites or videos**

Asking for pointers to tutorials and websites is off topic for stack overflow. However, are you familiar with the following resources?

- http://robotframework.org/#documentation
- https://github.com/robotframework/QuickStartGuide/blob/master/QuickStart.rst
- https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/robot-framework-tutorial-overview/

Answer (score 0):

Parameterization can be achieved using a csv or excel data source. Our team implemented it using excel, sharing the reference code that can help

http://www.ufthelp.com/2016/01/robot-framework-working-with-excel_28.html